# Add a "duplicate answer" comment template option in the Review Beta

Tags: feature-request, comments, review

It would be nice if we had a "duplicate answer" option in the delete modal of the Review Beta.

[image]

I realize it's not always obvious if an answer is a duplicate just by viewing it in /review. However, sometimes I click through to the actual post when I want to dig a bit deeper, and sometimes catch them that way. In addition to that, there are times it's obvious the answer is a duplicate just by viewing it in /review. For example:

[image]

**Edit:** Another example in response to [Robert's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144517/add-a-duplicate-answer-comment-template-option-in-the-review-beta#comment412011_144517):

[image]

The third answer should be deleted as a duplicate answer. It doesn't even belong as a comment since it doesn't add any additional insights. In essence it's a useless "me too" answer, and converting it to a comment makes no sense.

Comment: "This is really a comment, not an answer" fits your example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not really since I don't consider that post to even be worthy of a comment (upvoting Alex's answer will do). But in any case, that's just an example. Not all duplicate answers fall under the "This is really a comment, not an answer" category.

Comment: @ZulyGonzalez If you want this to be added, I'd think coming up with at least one example of something that should use this new flag is reasonable.  (Preferably more than one.)  If it's so rare that you have trouble finding them, then clearly this isn't a common enough case to need its own option.

Comment: @Servy I added a better example. The reason I'm requesting this is because I've encountered it several times already. It could be that this isn't a common problem on SO, but is common on the 2.0 sites.

Comment: As Robert says, the egregious example you show on top is well covered by "not an answer"... and the second example is not really a job for review IMO. It's not the reviewers' jobs to judge which answers provide additional insight, and which don't, and which ones are the originals. That's what the voting system is for.

Answer (score 2):

This really is a comment rather than an answer, and should be posted as a comment on the answer they're referring to.

It seems that **This is a comment, not an answer** is already the perfect choice for that, although the comment following that doesn't apply as perfectly to this case.

I'd suggest using that. Possibly

> This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author

should be changed to

> This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use the "add comment" below the question or appropriate answer to leave feedback or ask for clarification

Comment: I don't think your suggested text applies to the scenario I'm considering. I'm thinking of cases where the answer really is an exact duplicate of a previous answer and shouldn't even be a comment. Please see the additional example I added.

Comment: Right, I got distracted from the main point and focused on your first example.

Answer (score 0):

- If someone copy/pastes someone else's answer it would just be plagiarism (you would flag for that).
- If it's the same, or almost the same, as another answer but it seems reasonable that they came to the same answer independently, then both answers are fine.
- If it has the same basic message as another post, but it has much less detail, isn't phrased as well, or you just don't like it, it "looks good".  As long as it actually answers the question, being a duplicate isn't grounds for deletion (downvote, maybe).  If this is your own post self-deleting would be a good idea, but you should be deleting someone else's post just because you think another answer is better.

Comment: I disagree. From the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion): "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are … **exact duplicates of other answers** ..."

Comment: @ZulyGonzalez An exact duplicate would most likely be plagiarism, as my first point states.  Note that in your example it's not even an exact duplicate.  The one you say is a duplicate is quite a bit worse as an answer.

Comment: It's not a worse answer. It's the same answer.

Comment: When I say "answer" I mean the entirety of the text inputted into the "answer" box.  Not the single sentence ("NO").  The entire answer goes into much less detail, doesn't explain itself, etc.  That is what makes it worse.  The fact that it came to the same conclusion as another answer doesn't make it a duplicate.  If that were the case, there would be tons and tones of duplicates on most all questions, as they often don't fundamentally disagree on what the answer is, just how to explain it.

Comment: You are basically saying it's OK to have 20 answers that in essence are all saying the same thing. As far as I know SE has always strongly discouraged that practice, and considers it noise. That practice is allowed on forums, but not SE. We use upvotes on SE. We'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @ZulyGonzalez I'm not saying this should be encouraged.  I agree that this should be discouraged.  It should be discouraged through downvotes though, not deletion.